# How do I fetch all parents in a self relationship?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `User` table with a self relationship.

the table has the fields like it follows:

- `id`
- `parent_id` (FK to `User`)
- `name`

A User can have a parent, and this parent can have a parent and such on until infinite(although I will probably go like 3-4 levels tops the application sets no limit).

How do I fetch all the genealogical tree from a user that has no children(bottom of tree user) excluding siblings.

For instance:
I have `user1`, his parent is `parent1` which has a `grandparent1`. If `grandparent1` has other children(like a supposedly `parent2`) I don't want to fetch that. Just `user1`->`parent1`->`grandparent1`. Is there any way I can loop associations until it is not found?

**EDIT1: I really want to use QueryBuilder for this. Making a foreach calling a parent() method until it returns null will probably not be the best solution due to optimization**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that already. But should I just put this in a foreach until `parent()` returns null? It seems a little bit not-optimized. Is there any way to do this using query builder?